# Slide Responsivo Boostrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-3

Olá ,
Gostaria de adicionar um  full slide em meu head usando o bootstrap, igual ao exemplo da imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Poderiam me ajudar ?
Caso desejem visualizar minha estrutura estou deixando o link do meu repositorio no github:
https://github.com/luismatheusbs16/auto-jet.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver o seu caso, utilize o plugin Carousel do Bootstrap. É bem simples!

Cada plugin pode ser incluído individualmente ( no seu cado usando o arquivo "carousel.js" individual do Bootstrap), ou todos de uma vez (usando "bootstrap.js" ou "bootstrap.min.js").

Não funciona corretamente em versões inferiores a 10 do Internet Explorer.

**Indicators (carousel-indicators):** Adiciona indicadores para o carrossel. Estes são os pequenos pontos na parte inferior de cada slide (o que indica quantos slides há no carrossel e que deslize o usuário está atualmente visualizando);

**Inner (carousel-inner):**  Adiciona slides ao carrossel

**Para mais Informações consulte a documentação em**:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel
ou
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp

Segue Exemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Slider</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/luismatheusbs16/auto-jet/master/images/slide-pag-inicial.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Titulo</h3>
            <p>Comentários</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/luismatheusbs16/auto-jet/master/images/banner-pag-inicial.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
         <div class="carousel-caption">
         <h3>Titulo</h3>
            <p>Comentários</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/luismatheusbs16/auto-jet/master/images/slide-quem-somos.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
         <div class="carousel-caption">
         <h3>Titulo</h3>
            <p>Comentários</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Próxima</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado, vou fazer as modificações necessarias

Comment: Marcus no caso eu gostaria de adicionar o slide atras do menu e do meu logo, como se fosse o background do head